# Almost surely finite random variable

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a random variable X taking values in $\mathbb{Z}^{+} \cup\{\infty\} $. Prove that X is finite almost surely, given the following bound (a $\in \mathbb{N}$):

$\mathbb{P}(X>n) \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2+a}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2+2a}\right) ...  \left(1-\frac{1}{2+(n-1)a}\right).$

The fact that $\left(1-\frac{1}{2+(n-1)a}\right) \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ makes things quite awkward, since we want the right hand side to go to 0.

So far I have tried using the tricks $x=e^{log(x)}$ and $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>n)$ but haven't had much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that it is finite almost surely it's enough to prove that $\mathbb{P}(X>n)$ vanishes for $n\to\infty$, which is true if and only if
$$\log \mathbb{P}(X>n)\to -\infty\,.$$

What you have to check is that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{2+na}\right)=-\infty\,.$$

Now you have that for any $x>0$, $\log(1-x)\leq -x$. So
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{2+na}\right)\leq-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2+na}=-\infty\,.$$

Comment: Long products scream logarithms. Easy kill.

Comment: why $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X>n)=0$ implies $P(X<\infty)=1$?